# Aptana Team Environment?

Tags: aptana

I am switching away from Dreamweaver into Aptana. I am using Codeigniter PHP.

Iam trying to figure a good  environment setup. It is a small shop, 3 users. We have 2 external servers. One is for test builds for sites and the other is the live server for the sites.

I am used to Dremweaver where you can open a file from the remote site and it pulls it to your local. This does not happen in Aptana. It will open the remote file but then just saves it to the remote site.

So I need to come up with a way for the users to keep their files up to date as multiple people or working on the same sites.

The only thing I have figure so far is to just work off of the remote connections node and at the end of the day do a sync so your local has the latest files.

I would prefer to keep away from local testing environments. We have a testing server and that is what is for.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a good opportunity to introduce version control like git there. Aptana has some git integration built in so getting started with that should not be too difficult.

Comment: Soory for such a long wait. I got buried in a project and had to go with what I had. I have started trying the git stuff with aptana. It works for pushes, but I still haven't found a way to tell it to pull the latestest files on git. Also syncing with my 2 servers does not work. No matter what I do the sync feature thinks files have chaged on the remote that I know haven't.